# Why PowerShell threw registry access error when setting execution policy rights?

Tags: windows, powershell

I tried to [set execution policy rights in PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx) to enable the execution of scripts using this Cmdlet,

```
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

but the PowerShell console gave the `Registry access denied` error. The syntax seems to be okay. Did i overlook something. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run PowerShell with elevated permissions. Simply right click Windows PowerShell and click Run as Administrator to open PowerShell in elevated privilege.